# How to query posts from multiple parents

Tags: wordpress

I want to query the current page siblings AND children.

Using `'post_parent' => $post->post_parent` OR `'post_parent' => $post->ID` separately I get it to work.

But **I want to query them simultaneously**.

**I tried** to "merge" them using variables but it seems like it doesn't work. The output I get is all the pages on the site (same as post_parent is 0).

#### Full code:

```php
<?php
$mysibling        = $post->post_parent;
$mychild          = $post->ID;
$mychildmysibling = array( $mychild, $mysibling );

$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_parent'     => $mychildmysibling,  
    'sort_order'      => 'asc'
 );

$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'page',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'post_parent__in' => $mychildmysibling,  
  'sort_order'      => 'asc'
);
```

As written on this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

> **post_parent (int)** - use page id to return only child pages. Set to 0
>   to return only top-level entries.
>   **post_parent__in (array)** - use post
>   ids. Specify posts whose parent is in an array. (available since
>   Version 3.6)

Think about it as a MySQL question where you use the ["IN" clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) when working with multiple values.